# Oracle CURSOR Fetch

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a code like below:

```
CURSOR data_cur(username VARCHAR2)
IS
SELECT user_name as username,pass_word as password 
from User 
where user_name=username;

OPEN data_cur(username);
FETCH data_cur INTO data_rec;

IF data_cur%NOTFOUND
THEN
  vs_return := NULL;
END IF;
```

Now once the data is copied in to data_rec, is there any way that I get the value of something like `data_rec.get(password);`

And also my function declaration is getUserProperty(username, property).. Now let's say if I have lots of columns from the select query, then how could I return something **data_rec.get(property)** without hard coding like **data_rec.password**

Answer (score 2):

You can access the columns by using it as below.

```
data_rec.pass_word
```

Comment: My function definition is getUserProperty(username, property).. Now let's say if I have lots of columns from the select query, then how could I return something data_rec.get(property) without hard coding like you mentioned.